# Bash: Search for files with same name in different folders and execute them

Tags: php, bash, shell, cron

I'm trying to run every `wp-cron.php` included in my `/var/www/` subdirs.
I have multiple websites inside `/var/www/`, so I tried doing something like this:

```
find /var/www/ -ipath */wp-cron.php -exec php -q "{}" \;
```

But other files are executed, not related to `wp-cron.php`. What's wrong with the command above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct `find` command to find `wp-corn.php` is to use `-iname` or `-name` option:

```
find /var/www/ -iname 'wp-cron.php' -exec php -q "{}" \;
```

Comment: Nope, I get the same output of my command. It executes files not related to wp-cron.php! See: http://pastebin.com/TKUSMyW4

Comment: Oh wait ok, maybe that's the output of wp-cron.php called by the command

Comment: Why is -ipath deprecated? Is -iname better?

Comment: `-ipath` isn't deprecated but have different usages. `-ipath` lets you match full path of the filename whereas `-name` only allows matching filename part. In your case `-name` suits better.

Comment: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find
-ipath pattern: "Behaves  in  the same way as -iwholename. This option is deprecated, so please do not use it."

Comment: Thanks @MultiformeIngegno for the link, wasn't aware of it.